# From where can I download 64 bit libxml2.dll and mod_proxy_html.so files

Tags: libxml2, ibmhttpserver, mod-proxy-html

After migrating IHS (IBM HTTP Server) 9.0.5.2 to new 64 bit windows server, the 2 modules (libxml2.dll and mod_proxy_html.so) are failing to load. These modules seems to be working fine on the older IHS 8.0 
 - 32 bit. Hence, I am looking for 64 bit libxml2.dll and mod_proxy_html.so files. I have found the source code but I am not able to build it since I am not a C programmer. And code looks very complex with lots many dependencies on components not present in source code.
Can someone please help me to find the 64 bit versions of libxml2.dll and mod_proxy_html.so files ? Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

You should use non-IHS apache if you require modules that aren't built and shipped with IHS.  You may be able to use 64-bit 9.0.5.4 and fish these librarys out of an Apachelounge windows httpd build.